# Action sheet picker to show in landscape mode in ios8 on ipad

Tags: ios

I am trying to create country list on iPad in landscape mode but every time showing issue in ios 8 but working fine in ios 7. Please help me to resolve this issue to make it in landscape.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Please show your code here

Answer (score 0):

In `AbstractActionSheetPicker.m` in function `- (void)configureAndPresentPopoverForView:(UIView *)aView`
add preferredContentSize. the function looks like this after this and will work in iOS8

```
- (void)configureAndPresentPopoverForView:(UIView *)aView {
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.view = aView;

//Bugfix Landscape Mode iOS8
if([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredContentSize)]){
    viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.viewSize.width, 260);
}

viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = viewController.view.frame.size;
_popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
[self presentPopover:_popOverController];
```

}